# Query no filter by the field embedded in a collection in mongo with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

The problem is when I try to filter by the field embedded in a collection, for example:

```
s = Select.where('expired_date' => {'$gte' => Time.zone.today}, 'options.language' => "es")
```

The query returns:

```
irb(main):019:0> s.size => 1
irb(main):021:0> s.first.options.size
selector={"$query"=>{"expired_date"=>{"$gte"=>2015-11-11 00:00:00 UTC}, "options.language"=>"es"}
=> 2
```

Data insert:

```
Select.new(expired_date: (Date.today + 1.week), options: [{ name: "first name", language: "es"}, { name: "second name", language: "en"}]).save
```

**Select**

```
class Select
  include MongoidBase
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :options
  field :expired_date, type: Date 

  validates :expired_date, presence: true
  validates :options, presence: true
end
```

**Option**

```
class Option
  include MongoidBase

  embedded_in :feature
  field :name, type: String 
  field :language, type: String

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :language, presence: true, inclusion: { in:  ["en", "es"] }
end
```

In this case the filter is for the field language `(language => "es")`. This should return 1 instead of 2 because there is only one document with this value.

Comment: You don't have 2 documents containing options.language=es ?

Comment: No, only one. Check _Data insert_

Comment: You inserted only this document ? So you have only one document in all your collection ?

Comment: @MateoBarahona yes. Please, Check _Data insert_ in my question. Only exist one document(Select) with 2 embedded options.